# Click event affects only the first element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am writing an application where the user selects by toggling the switch button but the click event affects only the first element.

```
 <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="block-instructors" class="block-instructors" value="FMmRXgApuo5AZe4zGqUl">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>                                            
<label class="switch">
   <input type="checkbox" id="block-instructors" class="block-instructors"  value="J0jcK7eUvadzSNaaoG2h">
   <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>  

    $("#block-instructors").on('change', function(e){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).attr('value');
            alert($(this).val());
        }
        else {
            $(this).attr('value', 'false');
            alert($(this).val());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have the same id for two elements on one page. Use this instead

```js
$(".block-instructors").on('change', function(e) {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).attr('value');
    alert($(this).val());
  } else {
    $(this).attr('value', 'false');
    alert($(this).val());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="block-instructors" class="block-instructors" value="FMmRXgApuo5AZe4zGqUl">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>                                            
<label class="switch">
   <input type="checkbox" id="block-instructors" class="block-instructors"  value="J0jcK7eUvadzSNaaoG2h">
   <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use class instead of id:

```
$(".block-instructors").on('change', function(e){
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have defined multiple tags with same Id. Your jQuery function starts searching for the Id '**block-instructors**' and returns you where it finds first in DOM. You must convert **block-instructors** from Id to class and then access it

Answer (score 0):

You should have the unique id for individual element or tag. When you are clicking it is referring to last one since the code executes line by line. Try this code instead.

```
$("#block-instructors1").on('change', function(e,value){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).attr('value');
        alert($(this).val());
    }
    else {
        $(this).attr('value', 'false');
        alert($(this).val());
    }
});
$("#block-instructors2").on('change', function(e,value){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).attr('value');
        alert($(this).val());
    }
    else {
        $(this).attr('value', 'false');
        alert($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To select the first element or any of the first nth element in jquery can be done easily by :nth-child() selector in jquery

For example for 2nd li in ul:

```
$("ul li:nth-child(2)")
```

Reference can be found [here](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)